# Average data over multiple years in single table in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a dataset that has columns for month, day, year, and river gauge height. There are several data points for height within the same day. I want to have the daily average for each month and day, but I want the years to be separated into multiple columns so that for each month and day, I can see what the height was over all years in a single row. It would look something like the following:

| Month | Day | 2007 | 2008 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10.2 | 13.5 |
| 1 | 2 | 10.5 | 13.1 |

I tried pivot tables and avg over functions but I can't get it to work exactly how I want. Before I ended up with a code like the following:

```
SELECT month, day, AVG(height) as Date_Average_2007 
FROM wellington 
WHERE year = 2007 AND month = 1 AND day = 1  
GROUP BY month, day UNION
```

but I would have to do that for each year and I'm looking to make one large table that also can put in null values for days when the river gauges were offline (if possible).

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Assuming your DBMS supports PIVOT then just get the average by day, month and year and then pivot the resultset to get the years as columns

Comment: @RBarryYoung I didn't downvote, but I disagree with your opinion. I think a perfect question concerning SQL includes both sample data and expected result and also the RDBMS they use.

Comment: “Perfectly valid” and “perfect” are two different concepts

Comment: @NickW, I added that info. I'm using postgresql, PGAdmin 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres you can use the following syntax to "filter" each aggregate function

```
SELECT
      month
    , day
    , AVG(height) filter (where year = 2007) as Date_Average_2007 
    , AVG(height) filter (where year = 2008) as Date_Average_2008 
    , AVG(height) filter (where year = 2009) as Date_Average_2009 
    , AVG(height) filter (where year = 2010) as Date_Average_2010 
FROM wellington 
GROUP BY
      month
    , day
```

If that syntax does not work (perhaps an old version? or not using Postgres) then "conditional aggregates" can be formed by placing a case expression inside the aggregate function e.g:

```
, AVG(case when year = 2007 then height end) as Date_Average_2007
```

Either approach should allow you to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: I guess I'm using an older version because the second option worked. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - I forgot the parentheses for the filtering condition. See it working here https://dbfiddle.uk/bBrg5MjQ but the older syntax works in evey SQL db I have ever used - so it is still used a lot :-)